# Google Distance - Set waypoints as lat,lng

Tags: ruby, routes, google-directions-api

I am using [Google Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) from Ruby.

I have this object:

```
params = {
  origin: "37.88818,-4.77938",
  destination: "36.51903,-6.28014",
  waypoints: [
    {
      location:"Malaga",
      stopover:false
    }]
}
```

When I generate url all works fine:

```
uri = URI('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
```

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818%2C-4.77938&destination=36.51903%2C-6.28014&waypoints={%3Alocation%3D%3E%22Malaga%22}](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818%2C-4.77938&destination=36.51903%2C-6.28014&waypoints=%7B%3Alocation%3D%3E%22Malaga%22%7D)

But when I use (lat,lng) instead place name it returns error.

```
params = {
  origin: "37.88818,-4.77938",
  destination: "36.51903,-6.28014",
  waypoints: [
    {
      location:"36.72126,-4.42127",
      stopover:false
    }]
}
```

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818%2C-4.77938&destination=36.51903%2C-6.28014&waypoints={%3Alocation%3D%3E%2236.72126%2C-4.42127%22}](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818%2C-4.77938&destination=36.51903%2C-6.28014&waypoints=%7B%3Alocation%3D%3E%2236.72126%2C-4.42127%22%7D)

How I can define waypoints using (lat,lng) format as origin and destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the API, below are my observations

1. You are using JSON API of Google Maps API - [the documentation is available here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en).
2. The first URL you have shown as working is working by fluke. As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints),

   > Waypoints are specified within the waypoints parameter and consist of
   >   one or more addresses or locations separated by the pipe (|)
   >   character.

   Hence, The query param needed for first example is `origin=37.88818,-4.77938&destination=36.51903,-6.28014&waypoints=Malaga`.

   The effective URL will be [`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818,-4.77938&destination=36.51903,-6.28014&waypoints=Malaga`](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818,-4.77938&destination=36.51903,-6.28014&location=Malaga).
3. In order to use the latitude, longitude for waypoints, you can use `origin=37.88818,-4.77938&destination=36.51903,-6.28014&waypoints=36.72126,-4.42127`.

   The effective URL will be will be [`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818,-4.77938&destination=36.51903,-6.28014&waypoints=36.72126,-4.42`](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.88818,-4.77938&destination=36.51903,-6.28014&waypoints=36.72126,-4.42)
4. You cannot use nested Ruby Hash as input to [`URI#encode_www_form`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form) as it will produce improper query string.  You need to simplify your `params` as shown below, so that it matches the requirements of the API

   `params = {
       origin: "37.88818,-4.77938",
       destination: "36.51903,-6.28014",
       waypoints:"36.72126,-4.42"
   }`